# Calculating Normalized Root Mean Square Error

Tags: matlab, opticalflow

I am trying to calculate normalized root square error (NRMSE) between my optical flow estimation and the provided ground truth 
I think I calculated the RMSE correctly, However, the normalized always INF values !

Here is part of my code:

```
 % u , v ==> estimated flow 
 % cu , cv ==> ground truth flow 
 du=abs(u-cu);
 dv=abs(v-cv);
 % To compute Absulet error 
 AE= sqrt(du.^2+dv.^2); 
 AE_aver= mean (AE(:)); 
 % To compute End Point Error 
 EPE=mean(AE(:)); 
 % To Compute Root Mean Square Error  
  X=AE.^2;
  RMSE=sqrt(mean(X(:)));
  % To Compute Normalized Root Mean Square Error 
  Vg=cu.^2+cv.^2;
 xx=max(Vg(:)); 
 nn=min(Vg(:)); 
  NRMSE=RMSE./( xx - nn );
```

Could you please show me where is my mistake? 
thank you

Comment: code that we can not run? Post an estimated value of `u` `v` `cu` `cv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that `NRSME` can be `Inf` is if either `RMSE` is `Inf` or `(xx-nn) = 0`.

So, you need to check your data.  Either `cu` and `cv` are both constant (either scalar constants, or vectors with the same value in every element), which would lead to `(xx-nn) = 0`, or at least one of `u`, `v`, `cu` or `cv` has at least one entry that is `Inf`, which would lead to `RMSE` being `Inf`.

Comment: You are right ,,, I think the problem in the data not in my calculation.. I thought I did mistakes to calculate the normalization ! . I check the ground truth flow and I found the minimum flow equal the maximum flow ! .. That why it is INF